# How to format a single output value in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm new to Spark. Can someone please help me with the following error (see image attached). I tried to format pct to 2 decimals. I wonder why I can't round the output "pct" to 2 decimal places using format_number? Is that because I can only work with DataFrames in Spark? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: The problem is format_number method of spark gets a Column and not float, you should call the method like that: format_number(lit(pct),lit(2))

Comment: Thank you @ShemTov! It seems that your solution returns a column object:
output: "Column<b'format_number(9.141494435612083, 2)'>"

Any idea how I can get the numeric output like 9.14?

Comment: Also, a quick followup question, lit() needs to be used here, is it because in Spark only works with columns and rows?

Comment: You seem to be confusing the Column datatype and functions that expect it as an argument, with builtin Python functions. If your intent is to format the number with 2 digits behind the comma, use e.g. `print("%.2f" % pct)`.

Comment: 1. To get the numeric output you need to cast your result (example in scala: lit(1).expr.eval().asInstanceOf[Int]), i guess in python it`ll be similiar. 2. lit method just wrap you value into Column class that spark can use the abstraction of Columns (can be value/expression from any type).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to call Spark builtin function `format_number` which requires `Column` but you pass `float`.

Spark SQL builtin functions are intended to be used with DataFrames. The way you're doing it, you should be using Python formater for floats to output just 2 decimals.

```
"{0:.2f}".format(pct)
```

However, you could have been used it if you calculated that percentage this way:

```
df.select(sum((col("High") > 80).cast("int")).alias("count_high")
          , count(col("High")).alias("total"))\
  .select(format_number(col("count_high") / col("total") * 100, 2).alias("pct"))\
  .show()
```